# Removing only the numeric without affecting other numbers in the string

Tags: python, maya

I have a list of objects that goes as follows, for example:

```
['ref_2537_1_obj1', 'ref_8953_1_obj32', 'ref_1120_1_obj', 'ref_8919_1_obj143']
```

And I wanted to remove the numeric that exists at the end of each item in the list, so that it should be like this:

```
['ref_2537_1_obj', 'ref_8953_1_obj', 'ref_1120_1_obj', 'ref_8919_1_obj']
```

However, if I tried using `.isdigit`, it will remove the other numbers that exists. And if I were to use `[:1]`, `[:2]` or `[:3]`, it also does not seems to be the ideal case as you can see in my example where there exists between 1-3 digits at the end..

What is the best way to approach it?

Answer (score 3):

No need to use pattern matching (regular expressions) when `rstrip` is enough (it's faster, simpler and more readable) :

```
a=['ref_2537_1_obj1', 'ref_8953_1_obj32', 'ref_1120_1_obj', 'ref_8919_1_obj143']
print(i.rstrip("0123456789") for i in a)
```

Comment: You probably want to include `0` in your number list, otherwise it'll miss numbers like `10`.

Comment: I case one forgets what the digits are, one could use `a.rstrip(string.digits)` after `import string`. Not sure it's worth it...

Comment: cool, that works, however, I noticed that one of my item with the name of `ref_2537_1_obj14` which appears at the end of the list becomes `ref_2537_1_obj15` instead of having its numeric strip off.. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.sub` to substitute the ending digits (if there exist any) with blanks.

```
import re
a=['ref_2537_1_obj1', 'ref_8953_1_obj32', 'ref_1120_1_obj', 'ref_8919_1_obj143']
print ([re.sub(r'\d*$','',i) for i in a])
```

Comment: As in my comment to pistache, one of my item with the name of ref_2537_1_obj14 which appears at the end of the list becomes ref_2537_1_obj15 instead of having its numeric strip off.. Any ideas why?

Comment: [check this](http://rextester.com/ZPC18136)..it is working as expected.

Comment: hmm ok.. Perhaps because I am trying this with maya application `cmds.rename`, it is not working as expected with the command despite it does works...

Comment: By the way, is it possible for me to use the code and tackle in the middle such as changing the `_1_` first then strip the numerics at the end?

Answer (score -1):

Since the format is always the same i.e *obj* then some digits you can could just `rindex`  on `j` and slice:

```
In [5]:   l = ['ref_2537_1_obj1', 'ref_8953_1_obj32', 'ref_1120_1_obj', 'ref_8919_1_obj143']

In [6]: [s[:s.rindex("j")+1] for s in l]
Out[6]: ['ref_2537_1_obj', 'ref_8953_1_obj', 'ref_1120_1_obj', 'ref_8919_1_obj']
```

If you want to update the original list:

```
In [7]:   l = ['ref_2537_1_obj1', 'ref_8953_1_obj32', 'ref_1120_1_obj', 'ref_8919_1_obj143']

In [8]:  l[:] = (s[:s.rindex("j")+1] for s in l)

In [9]: l
Out[9]: ['ref_2537_1_obj', 'ref_8953_1_obj', 'ref_1120_1_obj', 'ref_8919_1_obj']
```